# How to Increment Visual Studio build number using C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, build-automation

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project that produces a file called: "**Game-Release.exe**".

This was configured under **Project Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Linker** -> **General**:

```
$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName)-Release.exe
```

I would like to take this a bit further by have an incrementing build number so I would have something which says:

```
Game-Release-Build-1002.exe
```

The number on the end should be an incrementing integer. I will be storing the build exe's on subversion so I think i would find this useful (although not necessary).

Perhaps there is a built in macro in Visual Studio that could handle this. Quite possibly I was thinking I could have a text file with the build number in it and have the compiler read, use and increment the number in the file each time the project is built. My goal is however to make the process as automated as possible. What is the best way to accomplish this?

If you offer an opinion, please also provide the code we can all share. Thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx) add-in seems like it would do the job.

**Update:** Your question specifically mentions using Visual Studio to increment the version, but there is nothing automated about that. Have you considered using Nant and a CI server? That way, it is easy to inject the SVN revision number into AssemblyInfo.cs equivalent for C++. Automatically, on the build server.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using svn to version your project you could follow the instructions in [this link](http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/03/integrating-the-subversion-revision-into-the-version-automatically-with-native-cc/) it works perfectly for me because I can track bugs in a release application using its version information and comparing the source code.

All information below is not included in the link:

- setup your rc file like this *version.rc*

  ```
  #include "resource.h" 
  #include "version.h" //<-----------Don't forget the include
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Version.rc
  //
  VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
   FILEVERSION VER_FILE_VERSION
   PRODUCTVERSION VER_PRODUCT_VERSION
   FILEFLAGSMASK 0x17L
  #ifdef _DEBUG
   FILEFLAGS 0x1L
  #else
   FILEFLAGS 0x0L
  #endif
   FILEOS 0x4L
   FILETYPE 0x1L
   FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
  BEGIN
      BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          BLOCK "040704b0"
          BEGIN
              VALUE "CompanyName", "Your Company Name"
              VALUE "FileDescription", "Your Application Description"
              VALUE "FileVersion", VER_FILE_VERSION_STR "\0"
              VALUE "InternalName", "Internal Name"
              VALUE "LegalCopyright", "CopyRight stuff - Copyright (C) 2015"
              VALUE "OriginalFilename", "yourapp.exe"
              VALUE "ProductName", "Your Application"
              VALUE "ProductVersion", VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR "\0"
          END
      END
      BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation", 0x407, 1200
      END
  END
  ```
- Next add *version.h* file to your project which defines everything, setup like this:

  ```
  #include "svn_version.h"

  #define STRINGIZE2(s) #s
  #define STRINGIZE(s) STRINGIZE2(s)

  #define VERSION_MAJOR             1
  #define VERSION_MINOR             0
  #define VERSION_REVISION          SVN_REVISION
  #define VERSION_BUILD               0

  #if SVN_LOCAL_MODIFICATIONS
     #define VERSION_MODIFIER "M"
  #else
     #define VERSION_MODIFIER
  #endif

  #define VER_FILE_VERSION   VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MINOR, VERSION_REVISION, VERSION_BUILD
  #define VER_FILE_VERSION_STR        STRINGIZE(VERSION_MAJOR)        \
  "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_MINOR)    \
  "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_REVISION) \
  "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_BUILD)    \

  #define VER_PRODUCT_VERSION         VER_FILE_VERSION
  #define VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR     VER_FILE_VERSION_STR
  ```

after this you can follow the [link](http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/03/integrating-the-subversion-revision-into-the-version-automatically-with-native-cc/) above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure VS2008 has that feature but I think you can do it with a post-linker event that runs a little script that make the task for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pre-build script (written in JavaScript and executed using the cscript.exe engine) that defines the major/minor release, gets the SVN revision number and generates a magic build number based on the current date.  The script then creates a version.h file that is used by the main application (and by the main apps resource file to create a VERSION resource).

Comment: Sounds great. Care to post it then?

Answer (score 0):

My own approach, including binary file stamping:

http://indiocolifax86.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/a-scheme-for-automatic-build-numbers-in-cc-projects/